# Using an android project as a library for a java project (for a PC based level editor)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

## The problem

I have an existing Android project for which I am trying to create a Swing based level editor (for my own use). I have therefore been trying to link the two together with the android project as a library for a java project since they'll share a lot of the code.

My understanding of how I needed to do that (in Eclipse) was as follows (given that being an android project it doesn't have a jar that I can just use):

- Go to properties->libraries
- Add the android project using "add class folder"
- Ensure the android project is ticked within "order and export"

This makes the source happy, with slightly odd imports of the form `bin.classes.NORMALCLASSPATH` but otherwise it compiles without issue. On running however I get an:

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/richardtingle/ballmaze/Vector2i`

## The question

How can I use the source code from an android project within a pure java project?

I'm also very happy to accept answers of the form; "That is not a sensible way to create a PC based level editor for an android app, do it this way instead"

Comment: I'd move the common source code into a common library, and have both the Android app and the Swing app depend upon that library. Then again, I wouldn't be writing a PC based level editor, as I don't write games, and I wouldn't be writing a Swing app, as I haven't done serious Swing work in 8 years or so... :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare I have a feeling it may well come to that, I'm not looking forward to it though as I have an "objects should render themselves" style so all rendered objects have a `render` method that is passed an android specific canvas

Comment: "all rendered objects have a render method that is passed an android specific canvas" -- well, that's *definitely* not going to work, as Swing does not have "an android specific canvas". Make abstract classes that have the bulk of the business logic, then concrete Swing and Android subclasses where the `render()` method resides.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah, I had a feeling that would be the case too. This is the problem with hobby projects; you just go for it without planning it out properly